# Как в Java вычитать HTML код страницы с нужным параметром в теге select?

Tags: java, html, парсер, jsoup

Вычитать HTML-код [страницы](https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/) для цены в EUR

При открытии сайта по умолчанию цена задана в U.S. Dollar и парсится без проблем:

```
String siteAddress = "https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(siteAddress).get();
```

И т. д.

А как быть для цены в EUR? Пробовал вот так:

```
String siteAddress = "https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/?currency=EUR";
```

Но всё равно высчитываются долларовые значения!

---

Переделал код, чтобы попроще, без Jsoup. Что теперь добавить ещё? Не очень понимаю куда здесь POST приделать :-(

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FuelPreisService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String siteAddress = "https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/?literGalon=1&currency=EUR";
        String httpContent = getContentOfHTTPPage(siteAddress);
        List<String> preisFuel = getPreisFuel(httpContent);
        System.out.println(preisFuel);

    }


    private static List<String> getPreisFuel(String httpContent) throws Exception {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] array1 = httpContent.split("data=");
        String st1 = array1[1];

        String[] array2 = st1.split("&titles");
        String prices = array2[0];

        String[] array3 = prices.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        result.add((array3[i]));
        }

        return result;

    }


    private static String getContentOfHTTPPage(String pageAddress) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URL pageURL = new URL(pageAddress);
        URLConnection uc = pageURL.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        try {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Оправляйте методом POST:

```
Request URL: https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/
Request Method: POST
FormData: literGalon=1&currency=EUR
```

В ответ получите 302 Moved Temporarily на нужную вам страницу.
Видимо это значение хранится в сессии.
Не забудьте прочитать, сохранить и подставить в следующий запрос куку из заголовка

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=тут будет id вашей сессии; path=/
```

Comment: Переделал код, чтобы попроще, без Йсоуп. Что теперь добавить ещё? Не очень понимаю куда здесь ПОСТ приделать :-( 
Код добавлен в первое сообщение

Comment: @Solenoid я в java не силен, но гугл знает - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260/java-how-to-use-urlconnection-to-post-request-with-authorization